Why the PDDL plan syntax is indicated to be wrong in Visual Studio Code?
I wrote a simple plan (switch-on, switch-off) which works in plan editor. However, I write the same plan in VS-Code and it indicates I have Errors. I have tried many times to change indentation, etc, but nothing seems to work. For some reason, this is the only action which causes errors but other action is not flagged by the system. Here is a screenshot. 

Maybe adding an empty parameters block would fix it?
